# Selecting objects from a feature layer by attribute using OR?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I need to select all objects from a feature layer where a certain field called ESTATE meets 'rule a' OR 'rule b'. I have managed to do so with the following piece of code:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_Optimity_All, 'fl_Optimity_All')
query = "ESTATE LIKE '{}'".format('Node Live')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('fl_Optimity_All', 'NEW_SELECTION', query)
query = "ESTATE LIKE '{}'".format('Node Planned')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('fl_Optimity_All', 'ADD_TO_SELECTION', query)
```

What I have done above is basically an OR query (using the ADD_TO_SELECTION option on the second select instruction). Is there any way to do the same thing but only with one "arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management" instruction?

Comment: Try running the selection using the "select by attributes" from the Toolbox. The go to The Georpocessing results and export the script to Python. Open the script using a text editor and see how it handles the OR statement. That should at least get you started.

Comment: Useful tip indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that this will get you closer:

```
query = "ESTATE LIKE '{0}' OR ESTATE LIKE '{1}'".format('Node Live','Node Planned')
```

However, each LIKE operator is also usually [accompanied by a wildcard](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm):

> The wildcards you use to conduct a partial string search also depend
>   on the data source you are querying. For example, in a file-based or
>   ArcSDE geodatabase data source, this expression would select
>   Mississippi and Missouri among USA state names:
>
> `STATE_NAME LIKE 'Miss%'`
>
> The percent symbol (%) means that anything is acceptable in its
>   place—one character, a hundred characters, or no character. The
>   wildcards you use to query personal geodatabases are asterisk (*) for
>   any number of characters and question mark (?) for one character.